# pointer displaying different value than expected

Tags: c, function, pointers, pass-by-reference

I expected the output of the following program to to be **5**, but the compiler is displaying **20**. Can someone please explain why?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int a=5;
 change1(int *p);

int main(void)
{
  int x=20,*ptr=&x;
  change1(ptr);
  printf("%d ",*ptr);
  return 0;
}
change1(int *p)
{
  p=&a;
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/246148/usage-of-double-pointers-and-n-pointers/246300#246300).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to modify a pointer, you need to pass a pointer to pointer:

```
change1(&ptr);
```

and then:

```
void change1(int **p)
{
  *p = &a;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're passing a pointer, which causes the function to make a copy. In order to change it you have to pass a pointer to a pointer.